# How to check if Socket is established before changing activity

Tags: android, sockets

Whenever I run my code, I am not being redirected to the next activity when my socket connection is established, instead it moves to else part and shows the fail to connect toast. I know it is connecting correctly, from the output of my other device. Is there something wrong with my IF condition? Or the "Socket != null" was incorrectly used?

```
public void connecttoserver(View view){
    final TextView txtenterlumens;
    txtenterlumens = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtenterlumens);

    if(!txtenterlumens.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        enterlumens = Integer.parseInt(txtenterlumens.getText().toString());
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        if(socket!=null){
            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(goToNextActivity);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fail to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            txtenterlumens.setText("");
        }

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter correct Lumens!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txtenterlumens.setText("");
    }


}
```

This is my socket creation code:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            setSocket(socket);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not seting socket in `connecttoserver` thats why its always null

Comment: Can you post the whole class file which contain connecttoserver() method?

Comment: @JozefDochan I have already set socket with this line of code. new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

Answer (score 0):

You are creating socket in `ClientThread` but verifying it in another class, but you dont retrieve it. Add this method to `ClientThread`:

```
public boolean isConnected(){
    return socket !=null
}
```

and then slightly edit your `connecttoserver` to this :

```
ClientThread ct = new new ClientThread();
new Thread(ct).start();
        if(ct.isConnected(){...}
```

Comment: Oh, i understand it now. But I'm still getting the same problem even when using your method. I don't get directed to the new activity even when it successfully connects

Answer (score 0):

You init socket on another thread, so the result can not get immediately. Let do something like below. I haven't test this code yet.

```
public void connecttoserver(View view){
    final TextView txtenterlumens;
    txtenterlumens = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtenterlumens);

    if(!txtenterlumens.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        enterlumens = Integer.parseInt(txtenterlumens.getText().toString());
        new Thread(new ClientThread(new EstablishListener() {
            public void onEstablishCompleted(Socket socket) {
                setSocket(socket);
                if(socket!=null){
                    Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fail to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    txtenterlumens.setText("");
                }

            }
        })).start();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter correct Lumens!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txtenterlumens.setText("");
    }


}

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    EstablishListener mListener = null;
    public ClientThread(EstablishListener listner) {
        mListener = listner;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            mListener.onEstablishCompleted(socket);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            mListener.onEstablishCompleted(null);
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            mListener.onEstablishCompleted(null);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// Create function interface for callback
public interface EstablishListener {
    void onEstablishCompleted(Socket socket);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. I decided it would be easiest if I do the check for socket connection and activity changing in the ClientThread instead.

```
 public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            setSocket(socket);
            if(socket!=null){
                Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```